# A more efficient mob pushing redstone circuit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to build a mob system where the pistons push the mobs.  The screen shot below shows my current design, but I'm thinking there has to be a more space/redstone efficient way to get at this.  Or is this as good as it can get?

[image]

Comment: what is the green "25" on your screen?

Comment: @ChargingPun Screenshot is from my creative world.  the green 25 is the experience level on that world.  My kids play a lot on that world and love punching sheep....

Comment: Ah, I see. I play minecraft on xbox, and we don't have experience... yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make your device smaller if you replace the piston with a sticky piston and put it in place of the top torch.

Put a block on it and you are done:
[image]

Comment: Let's see, that's almost half the redstone, and volume of device is 4 instead of 9?  SWEET!

Comment: john you do need a slimeball for each piston though (not that hard if you have found a slime chunk)

Comment: ratchet freak  Not a problem for me, I have a slime farm.  My biggest issue with my design was the space required.  This design is super compact on space usage.  Very nice.

Answer (score 6):

As ratchet freak said, you can cut the redstone use by adding a block.

Also, by alternating repeaters and single bits of redstone dust, you can cut your redstone usage by 1 per unit on average:
[image]

Finally, if you are pushing 3 block tall mobs rather than 2 block tall mobs, you can use an even more efficient system using tripwires shown here:
[image]

This increases the iron requirement per cell to 2 but cuts the redstone down to only one.